# How can I get the second Ice Beam in Norfair after getting the first Ice Beam from Brinstar and the Wave Beam from Norfair? (Metroid NES)

Tags: nes, metroid

So, when the `Justin Bailey` code is used, you start out with a very cool Ice Beam/Wave Beam combination weapon.

I wanted to accomplish this during a normal campaign, so I collected the first Ice Beam in Brinstar, then went down to Norfair and collected the Boots, Screw Attack, and Wave Beam. I then went to collect the other Ice Beam, but it appears that the only way to actually get to the Ice Beam is to already have collected it.

[image]

I could freeze the Squeept (circled purple guy), land on him, and them bomb my way to the left, but without the Ice Beam, I'm stuck.

So then I tried to approach it from the other side:

[image]

Except that you can't actually get through, you can bomb away the metal floor, but once there, you can't get through the purple wall, it doesn't open up.

So, **from my current position of having the Ice Beam from Brinstar and the Wave Beam, is there any way to pick up the second Ice Beam?** If I head straight to Norfair from the beginning without getting the Ice Beam from Brinstar, that would work, but Norfair would be pretty difficult to navigate without the Ice Beam, not to mention there may be other parts of Norfair on my way to the Wave Beam that are not navigable without the Ice Beam.

EDIT:

I don't think the room directly to the left of the Boots would be passable without the Ice Beam:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, you can get past the room with the boots by doing bomb-jumps, making it possible to retrieve the Wave Beam without getting any Ice Beams. But, it doesn't work how I want it to work; getting any weapon replaces the one you currently had, so no "mixing" occurs. Justin Bailey works out because it sets the appropriate bits. For each item in the game, one bit determines whether or not it has been picked up, and another determines whether or not Samus has it. The Justin Bailey code sets both "have it" bits active for the Ice Beam and Wave Beam. There isn't any way to do that in the wild without a code.

For the record, this code will start you off at the beginning in Brinstar with the Ice Beam+Wave Beam and Long Beam:

```
000000 000000
n00000 000034
```

Comment: this doesn't start you out with the wave beam.. its just ice and long, but it is a bigger shot

Comment: ice beam + wave beam = extra big ice beam